# ubercart 2 views - filter by order total weight

Tags: views, 6, ubercart

I use Ubercart 2 with [Ubercart Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_views). I'd like to filter orders based on total weight.

It's possible to add total weight as a field, however it is not possible to add this field as a filter. I tried [Views PHP Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewsphpfilter) using `$row->weight` but this filter is not picked up (it filters `$row->title` ok). How can I filter by total weight?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add custom php filter and add:

```
$ord_weight = db_result(db_query("SELECT SUM(qty * weight) FROM {uc_order_products} WHERE order_id = '$row->order_id'"));
```